# Thread with interruption in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question about threads in Java.

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = () -> {
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Hola");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("interrupted");
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }

    t.interrupt();
}
```

Why if I introduce an interrupt does it still enter the loop? (without break).

I understand the operation of the thread when there is an exception.

Comment: Because you can interrupt after the `!Thread.interrupted()` but before the `Thread.sleep(100);`. The exact timing of the interrupt is effectively random.

Comment: @Michael Ohh, thanks, I didn't know that interrupt is random…

Comment: With these sleep timings, the loop will be entered 20 times, possibly 21 - is that what you observe?

Comment: The interrupt is not random, it is just not deterministic when it happens. For example, the new thread might not yet have entered `run()` when you interrupt (although extremely unlikely with a sleep of 2 seconds), or it might have already entered the while loop (it takes some time to spin up and launch a thread, but the main thread might also have been paused to let a different thread/application run on the CPU, etc).

Comment: @f1sh The loop enter 19 times

Comment: Sleep resets the interrupt flag so if you don't use break  the while test never detects it. Add a call to Thread.currentThread.interrupt in the catch block.

Comment: @NathanHughes Yes, I think your answer the most accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the sleep method detects an interruption it resets the interrupt flag before throwing an InterruptedException. So if you don't use break then the interrupt flag is set to false by the time the exception is caught and the while loop test never detects the interruption.

The recommended practice is to add a line to your catch block like this

```
Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
```

if you want to keep the interrupt status.

It's not a problem here but be aware that Thread.interrupted() resets the interrupt flag. It's a convenience method used by some JDK code so that resetting the interrupt flag and throwing the exception takes less code.